# Ambiguous reference with a Picker in Swift UI

Tags: picker, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to make a Picker with SwiftUI. I've follow a tutorial but don't have the same result. There is Ambiguous reference on the self.category.count and self.category[$0]. After one entire day, I still don't know how to fix it ...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Picker : View {
    var category = ["Aucun", "BF Glaive", "Baguette", "Negatron", "Larme", "Ceinture", "Arc", "Cotte", "Spatule"]
    @State private var selectedCategory = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selectedCategory, label: Text("Item")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.category.count) {
                    Text(self.category[$0])
                        .tag($0)
                }
            }
            Text("Selected : \(category[selectedCategory])")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Ambiguous reference to member 'count’` is misleading. What you have is a naming conflict between `SwiftUI.Picker` and your `Picker` struct. Just change the name of your struct to something other than Picker. For example:

```
struct CategoryPicker : View {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can resolve the naming conflict between the modules by providing the fully qualified name for `SwiftUI.Picker` (as Sulthan pointed out):

```
SwiftUI.Picker(selection: $selectedCategory, label: Text("Item")) {
    // ...
}
```

However, I wouldn’t advise this option unless your intention is to replace `SwiftUI.Picker` everywhere in your app. Your code includes the `category` array and a `Text` view, so it's unlikely this is what you're after.

If the app eventually needs `OtherPicker` with a `SwiftUI.Picker` and the module name is omitted again, it’ll be even more confusing to track down the error—and you’ve already spent an “entire day” on it. So, best to avoid this possibility by not introducing the conflict at all :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve name conflicts between modules, you can either:

1. Rename your `Picker` to something else.
2. Use the qualified (full) name:

   ```
   SwiftUI.Picker(selection: $selectedCategory, label: Text("Item")) {
   ```

Comment: #2 is a solution. Maybe ill-advised though. You'd have to specify `SwiftUI.Picker` in every other view in your app that uses the SwiftUI `Picker` too. When another dev comes along and wants to use SwiftUI's `Picker`, they'll get this misleading error message and have no idea where it's coming from. Something to watch out for.

Comment: @JWK Usually the reason to declare your own `Picker` is to use it everywhere instead of the default `Picker`. The error is misleading because Swift compiler doesn't include qualified names in the error message, not because the name is bad.